# Python webbrowser.open() - setting new=0 to open in the same browser window doesn't work

Tags: python

Given this python code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://slashdot.org",new=0)
webbrowser.open("http://cnn.com",new=0)
```

I would expect a browser to open up, load the first website, then load the second website *in the same window*.  However, it opens up in a new window (or new tab depending on which browser I'm using).

Tried on Mac OSX with Safari, Firefox and Chrome and on Ubuntue with Firefox.  I'm inclined to believe that *new=0* isn't honored.   Am I just missing something?

tia,

Comment: I have seen something related.  If I have Firefox running with no open windows on a Mac, and execute `open -a /Applications/Firefox.app doc1.html doc2.html doc3.html`, it will open the documents in three new windows.  *But,* if I have a single window open, with no page loaded, then it will open the documents as tabs in that one window.  Odd, hm?

Answer (score 6):

Note that the documentation specifically avoids guarantees with the language *if possible*: http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open

Most browser settings by default specify tab behavior and will not allow Python to override it.  I have seen it in the past using Firefox and tried your example on Chrome to the same effect.

On Windows, it is not possible to specify the tab behavior at all, as suggested by my comment below.  The url opening code ignores `new`:

```
if sys.platform[:3] == "win":
    class WindowsDefault(BaseBrowser):
        def open(self, url, new=0, autoraise=True):
            try:
                os.startfile(url)
```

Comment: Thank you.   I have a large degree of control over the browser and how it's configured.  Have you seen any browser configuration where new=1
will work?

Comment: No, I just tried on Ubuntu/Firefox and Win7/Chrome with a few different settings.  This Python bug report of a similar issue claims that `new` cannot work on Windows but I can't get it to work on Ubuntu either: http://bugs.python.org/issue1753371

Comment: Ok, you inspired me to read webbrowser.py (surprisingly readable compared to my experience trying to read CPAN modules)... looks like there isn't any signal sent to open in existing window on Mac OSX _unless_ you call get() and specify a browser first.    I'll try that next

Answer (score 0):

I added a delay between successive invocations of  `webbrowser.open()`. Then each was opened in a new tab instead of a separate window (on my Windows 10 machine).

```py
import time
...
time.sleep(0.5)
```