# webbrowser python open new url in same tab. Does this ever work?

Tags: python, url, web, browser

It seems to me that Python's webbrowser 'new=0' functionality ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html)), which opens a new url in the same tab or window, is not ever working.

The documentation uses dodgy language like "*if possible*" to mask this problem.

Has anyone seen any success with this functionality in the webbrowser module? Are there any known workarounds to achieve this functionality?

---

I have tried setting the webbrowser with

```
webbrowser.get(TYPE)
```

before continuing with opening urls. I have also tried using a slew of different browsers, however still have seen no success. Is this just not possible anymore? Should I just use **selenium**?

---

Among others, I have checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997327/am-i-using-the-webbrowser-open-wrong-or-does-it-not-work-as-advertised-pyth) post from 7 years ago. I am hoping things have changed since then and people have found a way around this.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @causita no, sorry. I just rewrote what I had in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MacOS and Chrome and ran into this. I noticed that for MacOS, webbrowser.py just builds a little applescript and opens the URL with the 'open location' command, e.g.,

```
script = 'open location "%s"' % url.replace('"', '%22')
```

The built-in 'open location' command doesn't appear to support opening a url in an existing tab

I searched around in applescript examples and found that you can use commands from the Chrome applescript dictionary to open URL in the active tab like so:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        set URL of active tab to "www.google.com"
    end tell
end tell
```

I only needed to do this on a local project, so I just went with the dirty fix of overwriting the string in the 'script' variable to force it to use the latter format, like so:

```
# script = 'open location "%s"' % url.replace('"', '%22') 
script = '''tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        set URL of active tab to "%s"
    end tell
end tell ''' % url.replace('"', '%22')
```